# Show Rectangular image in circle

Tags: html, css

I'm writing a code where in I want to show my image in a circle type, but since, my image is in rectangle format I'm unable to do it. Here is my code.

```css
.imgContaier{
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 50%; 
  background: url('https://a.mktgcdn.com/p-sandbox/0UyvAqm29O_kNDqgTBdC-fK-rpqkrcFjQ66wI6seztY/150x150.jpg');
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
 <div class="imgContaier"> 
 </div>
```

The image is shown as a rectangle inside the circle. Please let me know how can I fix this.

My Image shows in a perfect circle only `120px` in height and width. How can I adjust it to show the same for `200px` of height and width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.imgContaier{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 50%; 
  background: url('https://a.mktgcdn.com/p-sandbox/0UyvAqm29O_kNDqgTBdC-fK-rpqkrcFjQ66wI6seztY/150x150.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-position: center;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="imgContaier"> 
 </div>
```

You can use the `background-size:cover;` this will apply the image to make sure it covers the whole container.

Do note that your picture has margins left and right so you will still see it as a rectangle, but that is due to the image source.

Comment: Yes that's seems correct. It was bugging me for a bit until I realised the image has the white margins.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you have is NOT a CSS issue - its a src image issue.... you are sourcing an image that is only 150px * 150px (and then as noted - has the white margins) .... so its not big enough to fill the 200 * 200 size container.

You can simply enlarge the background size to fill the space or use an image bigger than required.

**But the most correct answer is to provide image you are trying to insert to be the right dimensions for the container...**

This is allowing a larger image to fully fit into the round space you have at 200 x 200px

```css
.wrapper { 
display: flex;
gap: 32px
}

.imgContaier{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 50%; 
  background: url('https://a.mktgcdn.com/p-sandbox/0UyvAqm29O_kNDqgTBdC-fK-rpqkrcFjQ66wI6seztY/150x150.jpg');
  background-size: 250px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-position: center;
}

.imgContaier2{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 50%; 
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1595433707802-6b2626ef1c91?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8MXx8fGVufDB8fHx8&w=1000&q=80'); 
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="imgContaier"></div>
  <div class="imgContaier2"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.imgContaier{
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 50%; 
  background: url('https://a.mktgcdn.com/p-sandbox/0UyvAqm29O_kNDqgTBdC-fK-rpqkrcFjQ66wI6seztY/150x150.jpg');
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
 <div class="imgContaier"> 
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use regular images in combination with object-fit - that works much like background position and size

```css
.avatar {
  display: block;
  width: 6rem;
  height: 6rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border: 2px solid;
}


/* ignore this */
body { display: flex; gap: 1.5rem; }
```

```html
<!-- Avatar -->
<img src="https://unsplash.it/id/669/400/200" class="avatar" />

<!-- Original -->
<img src="https://unsplash.it/id/669/400/200"  />
```